# Como pegar um atributo de várias "tags" com mesmo ID

Tags: javascript

Ola, ao clicar em umas das 3 opções em "HTML" que está no código abaixo, quero que a função em "JS" emita um "alert" com o "idPost" em que foi clicado. 
EX.: Quando clico no link "PHP" ele emite um alert 25, que seria o idPost dele.
Mas quando clico nas outras opções a função não emite nenhum alert.
Se eu fizesse outras duas funções e alterasse os ids, sei que funcionaria, mas como se trata de um sistema de postagens, que seria minhas opções, ao adicionar uma nova postagem eu teria que fazer outra nova função, por isso usei os mesmos ids.
Espero que tenha ficado claro!

Codigo HTML:

```
<p id="linkPost" idPost="25"><a href="#">PHP</a></p>
<p id="linkPost" idPost="26"><a href="#">HTML</a></p>
<p id="linkPost" idPost="27"><a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a></p>
```

Codigo JS:

```
$('#linkPost').on('click', function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('idPost');
     alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Você clica em PHP? Isto não faz muito sentido, você quer dizer que em um documento php funciona o js, mas em um documento HTML não?

Comment: Tipo, isso é pra ser um sistema de postagens, isso são apenas teste, poderia ser outros títulos. Quando eu clicar em um desses título de mesmo ID queria que a função pegasse o idPost, que posteriormente usarei em outras coisas!

Comment: Continua não fazendo sentido o clicar no PHP.

Comment: O PHP seria o assunto de uma postagem, ao clicar nela abriria a postagem. O PHP é so de teste

Comment: Não importa o conteudo do teu PHP, o que não tem sentido é o que você perguntou, em outras palavras não da para entender o que você quer dizer com "clicar no PHP", para você pode até fazer sentido, mas lembre-se só por que você entende seu próprio problema não quer dizer que você consiga transmiti-lo para outras pessoas... Então edite a pergunta e faça um texto mais claro por favor. Grato.

Comment: as respostas do Rafel e do Sérgio resolvem o problema, porém, há um problema maior que é a semântica.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ID's duplos é HTML inválido. Usa classes em vêz de id.

Podes mudar o HTML para

```
<p class="linkPost" idPost="25"><a href="#">PHP</a></p>
<p class="linkPost" idPost="26"><a href="#">HTML</a></p>
<p class="linkPost" idPost="27"><a href="#">JAVASCRIPT</a></p>
```

e mudar somente no seletor de `#` para `.`, mantendo o resto do teu código como está. Ou seja:

```
$('.linkPost').on('click', function(){
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j4retqxb/

Ou podes usar como seletor `$('[idPost]')`, que usa esse atributo na procura em vez de classes ou ids. Nesse caso ficaria:

```
$('[idPost]').on('click', function(){
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j4retqxb/1/

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio

Answer (score 6):

Ao efetuar o clique, você clica no elemento `a`, logo, seu seletor pode mudado para `$('#linkPost a')`. Com isso podemos pegar o `#linkPost` utilizando a função `parent()`, já que `a` é fiho do `#linkPost`.

É muito importante você perceber que o HTML está inválido, pois não é permitida a utilização de elementos com o mesmo ID. Ao invés deles, você pode utilizar classes para elementos com propriedades repetidas. Dessa forma, o seletor muda para `$('.linkPost a')`:

```
$('.linkPost a').on('click', function(){
     var id = $(this).parent().attr('idPost');
     alert(id);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bm96ytvb/1/

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Comment: Caramba, nem percebi os IDs repetidos @Sergio. Gostaria que eu editasse minha resposta?

Comment: Pronto, obrigado pela orientação. Serei mais atento na próxima x)

Comment: Pois é, eu consegui confundir com os seletores do CSS e os elementos do C#. Editei mais uma vez.